# Context Menu in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, android-tablayout

How can I insert a Context Menu in a single Tab. For example, I click on the Sort Tab and I want to display a Menu with "Popularity, Increasing Price, Descending Price"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    mTabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Sort"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Filter"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Map"));
    for(int i=0;i<mTabLayout.getTabCount();i++)
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(imageResId[i]);
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    mViewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
    PageAdapter pageAdapter=new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mTabLayout.getTabCount());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if(tab.getPosition()==0) {
                registerForContextMenu((View) tab.view);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TAB SORT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```